# Easiest way to write/work with XML in Android

Tags: android, xml

I have an example XML file like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test1>
  <typ>task</typ>
  <datestamp>20150602153306</datestamp>
  <datecreate>20150602153306</datecreate>
  <task uuid="92F7F685-C370-4E55-9026-020E3CDCEDE0" status="0">
    <task_headline>TEST2000</task_headline>
    <task_subject>There is a Problem.</task_subject>
    <task_action>Solve it!</task_action>
    <task_priority color="#E62C29">high</task_priority>
    <task_memo></task_memo>
  </task>
  <task uuid="77783486-C370-4E55-9026-020E3CDCEDE0" status="0">
    <task_headline>TEST3000</task_headline>
    <task_subject>Another Problem</task_subject>
    <task_action>Solve it again.</task_action>
    <task_priority color="#E62C29">high</task_priority>
    <task_image></task_image>
  </task>
</Test1>
```

I want to figure out how I can search for a `uuid` attribute and do in this element different things such as determining if a child element is missing like `task_image` in the first element and `task_memo` in the second element.

I also want to add textcontent to `task_memo`.
I tried the following code, but it's not working:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new FileInputStream(new File(fileDir, filenameWithExt)));
NodeList taskList = doc.getElementsByTagName("task");
    
for (int i = 0; i < taskListLength; i++) {
  Node node = taskList.item(i);
            
  Node key = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("uuid");
  if (task_memo.equals(node.getNodeName())) {
    node.setTextContent(taskItems.get(position).get(task_memo));
  }
  if (task_image.equals(node.getNodeName())) {
    node.setTextContent(taskItems.get(position).get(task_image));
  }
}
```

Summary:

> 1. How do I search for uuid and work in this element?
> 2. How do I add some text to an existing `XML` element?
> 3. How do I determine if an element exists and if it doesn't, create it?

I know it's a very difficult topic and thats why I hope you can help me figure out how I can do these things.

Kind Regards!

Comment: Have you considered using SqlLite DB instead for simplicity and flexibility?

Comment: Not yet.I've read multiple times that SQLite DB is slower then using xml files

Comment: Is true that XML is lighter and fast but if using SQLLite will make life easier then I suppose that's one.of the hard choice we programmers face when comes to trade-off between performance and portability

Comment: I thought about it. But i can't decide. You are right... it's easier to work with SQLite because of availability and simplicity.... it's difficult to choose what's the best for this problem

Comment: For instance in your case taskContent can be sent to DB quickly and I believe SQLLite is very responsive as well if you not putting too much heavy data like BLOB in it. E.g. taskImage can be saved into File and its directory can be saved inside SQLlite

Comment: However I am not saying my suggestion is the best or only solution but I like to find simple and effective alternative to situation like this one.

Comment: So in case i use just simple and short strings and int values it's better to use SQLite DB? The only thing that could be big is a base64 encoded Image that is represented as string

Comment: If you getting image from with the data from web services then you can have the background service that decode the image and return image file path then save that into the DB, so when your e.g. Activity is getting the data, you will have another handler to load the image from.directory by passing the image filePath to it. Hope I am making sense.